# Database design question: multiple choice but free text when "others" selected

Tags: database-design

I want to make a website where users can register.

Let's say, when a user registers, the user has to input email, name, and job.
There are 4 options in the job field, for example: student, shoemaker, designer, others.

A user can select multiple jobs, and when 'others' is selected, the user can freely type text in `<input type="text" >`

In this situation, how should I create database?

Table `job`:

```
id   name
----------
1    student
2    shoemaker
3    designer
4    others
```

Table `user`:

```
id   name   email
-------------------------------
 1   john   john@example.com
 2   jane   jane@example.com
```

Table `user_job`:

```
id  user_id  job_id
-------------------
 1      1       1
 2      1       3
 3      2       4
```

The design above can't store the others' free typed text information.
What is the right design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional table, OtherJob.

```
OtherJob
--------
OtherJob ID
UserID
Text
```